# gradually make form appear problem "An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable"

Tags: javascript, css

i have a form, am trying to make it gradually appear each time i press next, i have two problems, first, there's an error that i don't know how to fix, it says "An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable.", i'm guessing it's because i have required fields and they're set to hidden, but i don't know how to fix it since i need the fields to be set before pressing next, the second one is the div that contains the form is in it's full form, it's like the form is all visible, if i use the display property it grows in size when the forms appear but i won't be able to make a transition like i can with visibility property, what should i do?

```
<form action="" >
        
                <label for="from"></label>
                 <select name="" id="from" required>
                    <option value selected disabled>select an option</option>
                    <option value="a">a</option>
                    <option value="b">b</option>
                </select>
                <br id="space">
                to: <select name="" id="to" required>
                    <option value selected disabled>select an option</option>
                    <option value="a">a</option>
                    <option value="b">b</option>
                </select>
   
            <br>

            <button id="dateBtn" class="btn">Next</button>
            
            <input id="date" type="date" min="2021-06-21" style="visibility: hidden;" required>

            <br>

            <button id="rangeBtn" class="btn" style="visibility: hidden;">Next</button>
            
            <input type="range" id="range" min="1" max="4" style="visibility: hidden;" required>

            <br>

      

            <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit" class="btn" style="visibility: hidden;"> finish up </button>
        
   </form>
    </div>



    <script>
        
            var dateBtn = document.getElementById("dateBtn");
            var date = document.getElementById("date");
            var rangeBtn = document.getElementById("rangeBtn");
            var range = document.getElementById("range");
           
          
            
            
            document.getEelementById("dateBtn").addEventListener("click", showDate()
            {
              date.style.visibility = "visible"; 
              rangeBtn.style.visibiity= "visible"; 
              dateBtn.Style.visibility="hidden";
            });
            
            document.getEelementById("RangeBtn").addEventListener("click", showRange()
            {
              range.style.visibility = "visible";
              timeBtn.style.visibility = "visible";
              rangeBtn.style.visibiltiy ="hidden";
            });
            
    
      
    </script>
```

Comment: Please share more details. Why is this question tagged with PHP, but does not contain any PHP code? Also, what have you tried to resolve the error message?

Comment: sorry wrong tag

Comment: the javascript wouldn't run at all, it has syntax error.  On both addEventListener calls, you can pass an anonymous function or function defined else where.  In your case you are trying to pass in an named function definition.  to correct this instead of `showDate()` and `showRange()`, try `function()`.